# disk full and "disk usage" doesn't help

Tags: command-line, 18.04, disk, disk-usage

My disk is full and `/home` directory is to blame from what I understood:

`sudo du -h --max-depth=1 | sort -h` from Home outputs :

```
40K ./.flipper
76K ./.pki
76K ./.vnc
92K ./.ssr
108K    ./Images
116K    ./.ICAClient
484K    ./.java
520K    ./.gimp-2.8
580K    ./Videos
3,5M    ./Pictures
4,2M    ./.mysql
32M ./.crashlytics
32M ./detekt
79M ./.vscode
123M    ./.nvm[
186M    ./usr
228M    ./Téléchargements
286M    ./lscGradle
298M    ./.m2
326M    ./.nvm
356M    ./.npm
458M    ./.mozilla
477M    ./.codestream
1,4G    ./.local
1,4G    ./snap
1,7G    ./.config
1,8G    ./Desktop
1,8G    ./Downloads
2,0G    ./node_modules
3,0G    ./.cache
4,9G    ./Documents
6,1G    ./app
9,1G    ./.gradle
9,5G    ./.android
37G ./Android
199G    .
```

Current Home directory weights 199GB. However adding the files doesn't fit.

Any ideas why?

**EDIT 2**

Using `du` with `-a` solved my problem
 `sudo du -ah -max-depth=1 | sort -h`
outputed a >100 GB hidden `.swp` file lol.

**EDIT**

to answer some comments (thanks):

- Disk Usage Analyzer can't locate nor find the missing space
- I don't use docker and co
- `df -hx squashfsdf` outputs :

```
/dev/loop10     615M  615M     0 100% /snap/intellij-idea-community/257
/dev/loop11     111M  111M     0 100% /snap/core/12821
/dev/loop12     219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77
/dev/loop13     135M  135M     0 100% /snap/chromium/1945
/dev/loop14     161M  161M     0 100% /snap/opera/167
/dev/loop15     161M  161M     0 100% /snap/opera/168
/dev/loop16      23M   23M     0 100% /snap/chromium-ffmpeg/26
/dev/loop1       62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1405
/dev/loop17     111M  111M     0 100% /snap/core/12725
/dev/loop18     2,7M  2,7M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/169
/dev/loop19     768K  768K     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/761
/dev/loop20     640K  640K     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/103
/dev/loop21     170M  170M     0 100% /snap/spotify/58
/dev/loop2      133M  133M     0 100% /snap/postman/95
/dev/loop22      95M   95M     0 100% /snap/slack/60
/dev/loop23     249M  249M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/99
/dev/loop24     128K  128K     0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop25     169M  169M     0 100% /snap/spotify/57
/dev/loop26     614M  614M     0 100% /snap/intellij-idea-community/265
/dev/loop27     768K  768K     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/741
/dev/loop28      56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2284
/dev/loop29     2,7M  2,7M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/174
/dev/loop30     141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/102
/dev/loop31      62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1376
/dev/loop32      83M   83M     0 100% /snap/scrcpy/379
/dev/loop33     2,5M  2,5M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/884
/dev/loop34     219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
/dev/loop35     163M  163M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
/dev/loop36     640K  640K     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/106
/dev/loop3       66M   66M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1519
/dev/loop37     130M  130M     0 100% /snap/slack/49
/dev/loop38      56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2344
/dev/loop39     135M  135M     0 100% /snap/chromium/1944
/dev/loop40     2,7M  2,7M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/920
/dev/loop4       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/chromium-ffmpeg/24
/dev/loop5      248M  248M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/87
/dev/loop6       83M   83M     0 100% /snap/scrcpy/371
/dev/loop7      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/104
/dev/loop8      296M  296M     0 100% /snap/vlc/2344
/dev/loop9       66M   66M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
/dev/nvme0n1p1  511M  6,7M  505M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/nvme0n1p2  234G  220G  1,6G 100% /
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           1,6G  2,1M  1,6G   1% /run
tmpfs           1,6G  4,8M  1,6G   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7,7G     0  7,7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           7,7G  148M  7,6G   2% /dev/shm
udev            7,7G     0  7,7G   0% /dev
```

Comment: Hello. Please do not post pictures of text. Include the text in the body of the question.

Comment: And also post the output of `df -hx squashfs`, please. (As text, using code formatting)

Comment: Do you use virtual machines or Docker containers? If so, many of the instances will not release storage space until *after* they have been shut down and restarted 

Comment: Looks like you are running Ubuntu Desktop. Rather than mucking about with `du` (which is great, but has a learning curve), use your Desktop Search to open Disk Usage Analyzer, which is included with every stock install of Ubuntu Desktop. Then you can see graphically what the big offenders are.

Comment: I edited my question thanks

Comment: Without the `-a`-option `du` displays only directories but not files, seems you have some bigger files in your home-directory.

Comment: If you have not rebooted your PC, then
Please try

    "sudo lsof /home | grep deleted"
To find files that are already deleted but still take up diskspace because a process is using it. 

If you kill the associated process, the space is recuperated.

Comment: the -a option saved me thanks !

Answer (score 0):

To analyze the disk usage within the command line one could use the tool [`ncdu`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/ncdu.1.html) which is a curses-based version of `du`. It should be installed.

```
sudo apt install ncdu
```

In order to analyze the user's home directory of the current user you can use the following syntax:

```
ncdu ~
```

In order to analyze the entire filesystem `/`, but ignore the mounted devices `-x` you can use:

```
sudo ncdu -x /
```

In addition while you are browsing the filesystem by `ncdu` you can delete some directory or file by pressing the `d` key. When you finish the analyze press `q` to exit.

Here is how its interface looks like.

[image]